# Default integer result to avoid dividing by zero in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

How do I create a default 0 value result for a calculated variable when the calculation divides by 0?

I am a beginner in SwiftUI and am trying to create a simple quiz app. In the app, questions by category are counted, such as "hsa" below (hsaCount.correct and hsaCount.incorrect) and eventually a score is calculated (scoreHSA).

The current code below works fine except when an "hsa" question is not attempted which results in "triedHsa" being 0 and an error of "Thread 1: Fatal error: Division by zero"

I am trying to figure out how to make the default scoreHsa result 0 if triedHsa is 0.

I tried using guard and if/else statements but failed, likely due to my inexperience.

```
let hsaCount: (correct: Int, incorrect: Int)

var triedHsa: Int { hsaCount.correct + hsaCount.incorrect}

var scoreHsa: Int { ((hsaCount.correct * 100) / triedHsa)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary expression:

```
var scoreHsa: Int {
  triedHsa == 0 ? 0 : ((hsaCount.correct * 100) / triedHsa)
}
```

Or, you can use conditional expressions:

```
var scoreHsa: Int {
  guard triedHsa != 0 else {
     return 0 
  }

  return (hsaCount.correct * 100) / triedHsa
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift is missing a throwing function for this; you need to make one yourself.

*(`option`+`/` makes `÷`)*

```swift
var scoreHsa: Int { (try? hsaCount.correct * 100 ÷ triedHsa) ?? 0 }
```

```swift
infix operator ÷: MultiplicationPrecedence

public extension BinaryInteger {
  /// - Throws: `DivisionByZeroError<Self>`
  static func ÷ (numerator: @autoclosure () -> Self, denominator: Self) throws -> Self {
    guard denominator != 0
    else { throw DivisionByZeroError() }

    return numerator() / denominator
  }
}

public struct DivisionByZeroError: Error { }
```

Comment: It's intentional that this is not a throwing function in Swift.

Comment: Nonsense. There were no errors in Swift 1. If they designed it today, it would have a safe overload.

Comment: They would definitely not do that for the `/` operator (that would be a nightmare for programmers and performance) and they wouldn't define a new operator just to catch division by zero. They could add a method on `Int` similar to `Int.dividedReportingOverflow(by:)`. I am pretty sure that if such a method existed, it would not throw an error, it would simply return `nil`.

Comment: `/`, just like `&&` performs exists as it does in Swift purely for the comfort of old people. New people don't have preconceptions about how these things should behave built up. I am neither new nor old but I'm very unhappy with the implementation of both operators.

Comment: Note that how `/` works is mostly defined by the CPU instructions. I have no idea what you mean by your comments about `&&`; there are not many ways how to implement a short-circuiting AND.